# Add new words to Bing sentiment Lexicon in R

Tags: r, rstudio, tidytext

Working on analyzing some comments using R Studio. I'm using Bing Sentiment lexicon from tidytext package right now.

I have some additional words that I wish to add to Bing (runtime or offline). For instance I can add them with level of positivity or negativity or any other sentiment. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sentiment` is a `tibble`, so adding new words is simply an `rbind` :

```
additional_sentiment <- tibble(word=c("verygood","verybad"),
                               sentiment=c("positive","negative"))

new_sentiment <- get_sentiments("bing")%>%
                    rbind(additional_sentiment)

tail(new_sentiment)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      word sentiment
     <chr>     <chr>
1   zenith  positive
2     zest  positive
3    zippy  positive
4   zombie  negative
5 verygood  positive
6  verybad  negative

joined <- austen_books() %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  left_join(new_sentiment)

head(joined[!is.na(joined$sentiment),])
# A tibble: 6 x 3
                 book        word sentiment
               <fctr>       <chr>     <chr>
1 Sense & Sensibility respectable  positive
2 Sense & Sensibility        good  positive
3 Sense & Sensibility    advanced  positive
4 Sense & Sensibility       death  negative
5 Sense & Sensibility       great  positive
6 Sense & Sensibility        loss  negative
```